# WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast

Tags: python, ip, scapy, mac-address

Why it is giving me this error ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider accepting correct answers (clicking on the checkmark left to the answer text) as it helps SO contributors to identify the questions that still deserve attention.

Answer (score 1):

Your are doing the wrong encapsulation.  Basically you are putting an Ethernet frame inside an ARP packet which does not make any sense.  Hence the MAC destination address scapy is trying to reach is encoded somewhere in the ARP packet.

Try replacing:

```py
packet = request / boardcast
```

by:

```py
packet = boardcast / request
```

(typo: `boardcast` -> `broadcast`)